# How to shade or add grey overlay to non-selected features in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, symbology

I have an application showing cadastral parcels. When a parcel is clicked, the applications makes zoom to the extent of this feature and prepares a floating pane where it is possible to load some layers specific to that parcel.

The problem is that I think that when the studied feature is clicked, there are lots of lines, points and polygons around that feature, **so it is a bit difficult to concentrate** in the feature that user is studying.

So I would like to know how can I **add a shade or a grey overlay to everything that is NOT the selected feature**, so the user has highlighted only what has selected. Then, clicking on a close button or similar, shade has to go out. Yes, it is a pure aesthetic question, but I would like to give to my application a serious and professional look. :-)

Please, consider that at this point, there could be up to 5 or 6 different layers loaded in the map.

Does anyone know how to do this process? I am **not sure if it is possible to hide everything except one feature of one of the loaded layers**.

PD - Just to provide an example. Check the first item of the "What I would like to do" section in [this question.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17184/method-to-shade-or-overlay-a-raster-map-to-reflect-time-of-day-and-ambient-light)

Answer (score 1):

When the user clicks the map perform a query task on the layers you would like the user to be able to select. The identify will return a feature geometry which you could then add to the map as a graphic. Having added the graphic loop through all of the layers and set the opacity to 0.5 which will fade them out (not grey them out). The only issue I can see with this approach is matching the symbology of the selected feature, but normally you would change the symbology of a selected feature anyway. If you wanted to keep symbology perhaps you could add a duplicate Feature Layer (a duplicate for each of the tile/dynamic layers you want them to select) which is used in [MODE_SELECTION](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm) so the feature would be returned when the user selects. I assume feature layers return the symbology, I haven't really used them that much.